# Recurring Exponential Integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

When I tried to solve the below integral  by parts, its producing recurring integral, seems like its improper and cant be solved.

$$ I = \int_{\sqrt{A}}^\infty e^{-x}-e^{-x-b\sqrt{-A+x^2}}\,dx $$

which numerical integration technique is applicable on this form?

Comment: Tip: Using TeX symbols with $ makes it easier to read...

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I m new to math,stackexchange. Noted your comment :)